# What if I think my question would be better on a different SO/SE site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation

This morning I created a question on SO about [TWAIN and the Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044622/what-is-the-state-of-twain-on-the-macintosh-today) and got zero responses.

Looking at it again, I'm not sure if it would be a better fit for Super User or Programmers SE... or if it's just not a question that's going to get answered.

So, questions:

1. Is there any way I can draw attention to the question to maybe get someone to move it?
2. Would re-posting it on one of the other sites be an incredible no-no?
3. Does anyone here have an opinion on where this particular question would fit best?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any suggestions for your specific question. So let's think about a general situation where your question does belong on another site and you actually want it elsewhere.

Waiting for mechanical migration is only necessary if there's some kind of productive acknowledgement that you need transferred: answers and/or comments which address the problem. In the absence of these, then instead of waiting for someone to migrate one should just copy the body and title of their question, delete it from the first site, and repost it on the new site. This is going to basically mirror the effects of migration, but saves your time that would be spent waiting and saves the time of those who would have to move it.

The only thing migration offers in the above scenario is to keep upvotes, and if you got enough question upvotes that keeping them is really worth it, then the vested interest by the first site's community should cause you to think deeply about whether moving it is really necessary.

If there are answers and/or comments which would be useful to keep, then this is when you should try to draw attention. As mentioned [in some direction by Popular Demand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68862/what-if-i-think-my-question-would-be-better-on-a-different-so-se-site/68863#68863), flagging for moderator attention or posting on Meta is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to post it at [Apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com)—and again, it's a beta site, so cross-posting it manually would be the way to go.

<sub>I suppose I should note that I'm a moderator over there…</sub>

Comment: +1 'cause you're a mod.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... it's about code, but not specific code. I'd go with Programmers SE in this case. In my opinion, you're okay to just re-post, since it's still in beta and there's no migration path to beta sites.

As for drawing attention, posting here on MSO is usually a good bet. You can also flag for mod attention with the "flag" link under the question (works for answers, too).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there any way I can draw attention to the question to maybe get someone to move it?

Flag for moderator attention, saying "please migrate my question to XXX", if you're sure that's a migration path.  (If it is, it's listed as an option under the "off-topic" close reason.)  Also, you should vote to close (if you can) as off-topic, selecting the appropriate site.

> 2. Would re-posting it on one of the other sites be an incredible no-no?

Not necessarily.  If you're unsure if there's a direct migration path or if there just isn't, then repost it, vote to close as off-topic (if you can), update the top of the question with a link ("Moved to XXX"), and flag for moderator attention saying "please close my question, which I have reposted".

If someone has posted a particularly good answer you want to make sure gets moved, you can include a link back from the reposted question and should leave a comment on that answer asking them to manually move it.

---

You could simply delete the question (if it meets the criteria) from the original site, but then you'd lose anyone who might be watching for updates and new answers.  Unless you had posted the answer very recently, I'd prefer manual or automatic migration.